# How to join variables in PHP

Tags: php

How can I join **'<'** and 'div>'?

When I echo

```
<?php echo "<"."div>";?>
```

it returns an empty string.

Comment: Well, its printed. The problem is that every major browser is not accepting these tags and ignores them. When you watch the source of the page, you will see the stray div tag.

Comment: `<?php echo "&lt;"."div&gt;"; ?>`

Comment: `<?php echo "<"."div>hello</div>";?>` or use htmlentities method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is a HTML Tag. You cannot print it like this.
Still if you want to print it you can see @egig's suggestion. You can use `echo "&lt"."div&gt;"`

Comment: +1, Waiting for someone point out `"&lt;"."div&gt;"` and finally you

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're echoing a HTML tag. View the source of the page.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>");
```

to display html tags in php

Answer (score 0):

You can use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for this.

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars("<"."div>"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is executed and the '<' is joined with the 'div>', however there is nothing to show as you are trying to output a partial HTML tag in PHP. You can do this by means of entity code:

```
<   Less-than       &lt;
>   Greater-than    &gt;
```

In your case it looks like:

```
echo "&lt;"."div&gt;";
```

Other means of doing this is using PHP to add these entity codes for you:

```
htmlentities — convert all applicable characters to HTML entities
```

In code:

```
echo htmlentities('<div>');
```

Make sure you use echo, or otherwise you would end up with an empty string again.

Other means:

```
htmlspecialchars — convert special characters to HTML entities
```

In code:

```
echo htmlspecialchars('<div>');
```